# No Such Column Sugar ORM only in release version

Tags: android, database, sugarorm

I'm using codes as shown below, but somehow everything is working perfectly fine in debug version but as soon as I compile release version of the app, I get the error.

`no such column: IMAGE_ID`

Currently using sugarORM version 1.3 also using proguard

```
    public class Favorite extends SugarRecord<Favorite> {
        private int imageId;
        private int licenseId;

     public Favorite(int imageId, int licenseId){
            this.imageId = imageId;
            this.licenseId = licenseId;
    }
}
```

This is the query i am using to find the **image_id**

```
List<Favorite> favorites = Favorite.find
                (Favorite.class, "IMAGE_ID = ?", ((String) ("" + imageId)));
        if (!favorites.isEmpty()) {
            return favorites.get(0);
        }
```

I've tried using `image_id` `Image_Id` `image_Id` `image_ID` and few other
but I always get error 
`no such column exception in my release version of my application.

I have also tried many suggestion asked in the such type of question(s) but nothing is working as expected.

Comment: It will be great, if you add valid reason for downvote

Comment: Have you tried changing the access modifiers on imageId and licenseId to package protected?  This is how the examples are set up in the documentation.

Comment: first, obviously: imageId != image_id (**edit**: as Harsh pointed in his comment it doesn't matter, my bad)... second: are you using proguard in release build?

Comment: @Selvin yes i'm using proguard. imageId == ? ( to what ), as per docs it will convert to underscore one.

Comment: And of course you google for usage SugarORm with proguard and protected your classes from being obfuscated?

Comment: No need to be rude @Selvin.  Also, imageId will be IMAGE_ID in the database, as this is how sugarORM handles camel case fields.

Slevin is correct in that you should make sure proguard isn't stripping your generated classes

Comment: I edited my comment ... also i do not think i'm rude ... it is my normal way of communication :) ... also i'm always assuming that at least minimal work was done before asking the question here

Comment: Just updated proguard setting from getting obfuscating the model I hope it will work. Will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using SugarORM with proguard, which also obfuscate the model ( databases ) classes.

In order to use SugarORM with proguard you need to update proguard setting so that will it not obfuscate your database classes.

```
-keep public class com.youcompany.appname.xx.<ClassName> extends SugarRecord{*;}
-keep public class com.youcompany.appname.XX.<ClassName> extends SugarApp{*;}
```

Answer (score 3):

AS @Harsh mentioned you need to add rules to skip the obfuscation of classes are extending SugarRecord and SugarApp.This is just another way of doing the same thing.

```
 #skip every public class that extends com.orm.SugarRecord 
 #and their public/protected members
 -keep public class * extends com.orm.SugarRecord {
  public protected *;
}
-keep class com.orm.** { *; }
```

Related Issues

https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/219

https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/395

**Extra:**
Use following rule to enable  line numbers in logcat when running a proguard enabled apk build,     be sure to remove when publishing.

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Otherwise logcat lines will be like following

> at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.b(Unknown Source)

**Make sure to remove it when publishing.**